# What is the Java (Android) equivalent for Cocoa's NSDateFormatter?

Tags: java, iphone, android, objective-c

I have the following code in Objective-C for the iPhone, using NSDateFormatter:

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
if ([dateString isEqual:@"2010-11-12"]) {
```

What would be the equivalent to the NSDateFormatter used there in Java on Android?  I'm still fairly new to Java and Android development.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question title

Comment: You should start by spending some time with the Android Developer guide http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html (and perhaps also some Java tutorials if that is new to you http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). We don't do the work for you. If you, after reading the guide, encounter a specific problem, you should come back here and ask, and we'll be glad to assist.

Comment: @Nailuj actually i was seeking a function equivalent to NSDateFormatter

Comment: fair enough. But for future references, I would then suggest to rephrase the question to "What is the Java equivalent of NSDateFormatter" (etc.), so it doesn't look like you just want us to translate a piece of code for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure java code equivalent is:

```
        Date today = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dateString = dateFormat.format(today);
        if (dateString.equals("2010-11-12")) {

        }
```

But why are you formatting the date and comparing it against a string instead of checking the date object itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
final Date now = new Date();
final Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
if (formatter.format(now).equals("2010-11-12")) {
    // Do something
}
```

Note, the default constructor of java.util.Date initializes it to the current time